# Backend model _afterSave _afterLoad methods?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

I am making a simple plugin that would save some data to DB when you click "Save Config" button in system configurations. I have added this to my system.xml

```
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<backend_model>storesave/config_save</backend_model>
```

And in Save.php I am using _afterSave() method. I select the 'yes', but it does not run the code the first time "Save config" button is clicked. It only runs the code after I click the button second time. But when I select 'No' option and press "Save config" it reruns the code before save happens.

So I tried the _afterLoad() method, but if it was saved with 'yes' option selected, it runs the code the moment I go to my config page before I even press "Save config".

Finally I tried Using both methods to make a workaround.

```
public function _afterSave(){
    $this->saveState = true;
}

public function _afterLoad()
{   
    if($this->saveState == true){
        //execute code here
    }
}
```

But the _afterLoad() method does not trigger this way because $saveState always remains false.

So I would like to know why is this happening, and how could I make it work?

EDIT:

I use this as a check for `yes` `No` options:

```
   const XML_PATH_ENABLED = 'storesave/global/status';
    public function isEnabled(){
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED);
    }
    public function _afterSave()
    {
        if ($this->isEnabled() == true){
            //run the code
        }
    }
```

Even with this if selected state is `Yes` and I set it to `No` and Press "Save config", the `_afterSave` method still runs the code inside my if statement. So my thought is that how to make it not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the default value for your option is `Yes`. Magento has a short-circuit mechanism to prevent most of the code in save from triggering if the data on a model is the same as the data on the model at the point it was loaded (see `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save()`. The code you place in `_afterSave` will therefore only get triggered if the option actually changes (which in most cases is all you really want, but your requirements may be different). As you have found the `_afterLoad` method will get triggered when you load the page, not just when you click save.

If your requirement is to always trigger your custom code, only when save is called, the best bet will be to simply override the `save` method itself.

```
public function save()
{
    // do your custom work here
    parent::save();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works much better, but the problem remains that, when I select 'No' and press 'Save config', it still reruns the code creating duplicate data. And putting `parent::save();` before my code does not change anything.

Comment: Without knowing what your custom code does, it's impossible to give advice. It sounds like you just need to add protection to your custom code so that if you've already performed the action previously you don't do it again. In this case `_afterSave` is almost perfect for what you need with the exception that it won't get triggered the very first time due to the default value.

Comment: That is the problem, that even with the `_afterSave` if default is `Yes` and I select `No` and press save, it still reruns the code. So that is why I asked how to prevent that.

Comment: Return the code? It's really not clear what you are attempting to do. I (and I suspect others) will be unable to help further without an explanation of what your custom code is actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, I might not be very clear, hope extra edit might help provide more info of what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: That makes a little more sense. The call to `getStoreConfig` will return the value cached at the start of the request, not taking into account the change. Assuming the XML path points to the same field that has the `backend_model` set on it, you can use `$this->getValue()` to determine if it is currently yes or no.